# How to transform a 3d arrays into a data frame such that the third dimension becomes a list entry to the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, opencv, numpy-ndarray

I have a 3d arrays as follows:

```
img = array([[[33, 33, 33],
        [33, 33, 33],
        [33, 33, 33],
        ...,
        [32, 32, 32],
        [34, 34, 34],
        [45, 45, 45]],

       [[33, 33, 33],
        [33, 33, 33],
        [33, 33, 33],
        ...,
        [32, 32, 32],
        [34, 34, 34],
        [45, 45, 45]],

       ...,

       [[33, 33, 33],
        [33, 33, 33],
        [33, 33, 33],
        ...,
        [32, 32, 32],
        [34, 34, 34],
        [45, 45, 45]],

       [[33, 33, 33],
        [33, 33, 33],
        [33, 33, 33],
        ...,
        [32, 32, 32],
        [34, 34, 34],
        [45, 45, 45]]], dtype=uint8)

img.shape ##(1125, 2000, 3)
```

It is obtained by cv2.imread().
My objective being converting this 3d array into data frame keeping the RGB values intact.
One way is to convert it into grayscale so that it gets converted into a 2d array but that will not sustain the RGB values.

Required Output :
DataFrame

```
    0           1           2           ... 1997        1998       1999 
0   [33,24,54]  [33,55,64]  [33,45,23]  ... [33,33,32]  [53,33,32] [39,33,32]
1   [33,22,33]  [33,76,34]  [33,78,56]  ... [43,39,32]  [13,33,32] [36,32,31]
2   [33,24,64]  [33,55,45]  [33,89,78]  ... [63,36,32]  [83,33,32] [38,33,36]
... ...         ...         ...         ... ...          ...        ... 
1124 [56,24,61] [33,12,42]  [38,81,72]  ... [68,32,35]  [83,33,32] [78,43,66]   

1125 rows × 2000 columns
```

I am confused about how this can be achieved. Please help !!

Comment: Not a good idea at all to convert the numpy array into that structure. You'll lose all numpy vectorization capabilities, and pandas isn't efficient either with nested data structures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DataFrame.from_records` method

```
img_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(img)
```

You will get a dataframe with `img_df.shape = (1125,2000)`